# how to make sure that before repaint () cleared all the contents of the Jframe?

Tags: java

how to make sure that before repaint () cleared all the contents of the Jframe? doing something like a stopwatch just turns out that the figures on top of one another are drawn

---

Comment: [SOME CODE](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful in your question

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question well, what you need to do is draw a rectangle with the background color as big as the area you want. That effectively "clears" the area and you can draw on a clean "canvas" again